# @synthesize practice objective-c with user-interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

I blocked on an issue since 1 hours about Setter/Getter on objective-c

I implement the code below to do some action depending on user choose.

In my view controller interface :

```
@property  NSString* view_test;
```

In my implementation

```
@synthesize view_test;
```

The user acces to an other view after a click on a button with this method

```
- (IBAction)PPBarButtonClick:(id)sender {
    [self setView_test:@"test"];
    NSLog(@"view_test %@", [self view_test]); // Print test
}
```

And after my viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"view_test %@", [self view_test]); // print always null

    if ([[self view_test] isEqualToString:(@"test")]) {

      //some action

    } else {

      // other action

    }

}
```

And my trace

```
2016-04-04 07:44:43.266 MyApp[19926:675795] view_test (null)
2016-04-04 07:45:11.817 MyApp[19926:675795] view_test test
2016-04-04 07:45:11.925 MyApp[19926:675795] view_test (null)
```

I don't understand why after setting "test" to view_test, the print return (null)? I'm lost

Thanks

Comment: So the call of `PPBarButtonClick:` happens after `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Try changing your two log statements to: `NSLog(@"self %p | view_test %@", self, self.view_test);`. This will print the object identity as well as the property value. Do you have the same object in each case?

Comment: @CRD No the issue could be here : 
2016-04-04 20:56:09.878 MyApp[21255:724305] self 0x7feac3c3d4a0 | view_test test
2016-04-04 20:56:09.970 MyApp[21255:724305] self 0x7feac3dbb160 | view_test (null)

Comment: You have managed to create multiple objects where you expect to have just one. You then set the property value on one of them and try to read the value for another. You will have to work out where you are doing this, it is not in the code you have posted. HTH

Comment: @CRD ok but I don't know why self is changing. How I can create an object before the viewDidLoad ?

Comment: You have either: called `init`/`new` etc. more than once; or have created an object in your xib/storyboard and created another in your code. You might wish to use the debugger to step through your code watching the value of `self` to see where the objects are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

apply this code

```
 - (IBAction)PPBarButtonClick:(id)sender {
        // Print test
NSLog(@"view_test %@", [self view_test]); // print always null

        if ([[self view_test] isEqualToString:(@"test")]) {

          //some action

        } else {

          // other action

        }


    }
```

And after my viewDidLoad method:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
[self setView_test:@"test"];
        NSLog(@"view_test %@", [self view_test]); 

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks to be very old and there are a number of things you need to change in your code that will modernise it, and make it simpler and easier to debug.

Firstly, declare properties like this

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *view_test;    
@end
```

Second, you don't need `@synthesize` anymore. The only time this is required these days is when implementing properties declared in protocols.

Thirdly, whilst you can access properties using `[myController view_text]` and `[myController setView_text]`, I don't recommend it. My rule is that if something is declared as a property, it should be accessed using property dot notation. i.e. `myController.view_text`. So

```
NSString *text = myController.view_text;
myController.view_text = @"abc";
```

Now for your problem. Seeing a null followed by 'test' makes sense because `viewDidLoad` will be called before the view is available for the user to press the button on. Thus your if block will always call the else block in `viewDidload`.

There is nothing obvious as to why there is a second null in the log. Perhaps your view is being reloaded, or something else is setting view_text to null.

Comment: Loading the view a second time would not be enough. It seems to be a completely fresh instance of the view controller. (Sidenote: copy actually might be the better choice than strong.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I followed an old tutorial. But my issue is still here. I tried to add the [super viewDidLoad]; after the self.view_test but it's the same problem